# Does JDBC getGeneratedKeys() method always same order of inserted element

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I use `executeBatch()` with JDBC to insert multiple rows and I want to get id of inserted rows for another insert I use this code for that purpose:

```
insertInternalStatement = dbConncetion.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD, generatedColumns);

for (Foo foo: foosHashSet) {

    insertInternalStatement.setInt(1, foo.getMe());
    insertInternalStatement.setInt(1, foo.getMe2());
    // ..
    insertInternalStatement.addBatch();
}
insertInternalStatement.executeBatch();

// now get inserted ids
try (ResultSet generatedKeys = insertInternalStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {

     Iterator<Foo> fooIterator= foosHashSet.iterator();
     while (generatedKeys.next() && fooIterator.hasNext()) {

         fooIterator.next().setId(generatedKeys.getLong(1));

     }
 }
```

It works fine and ids are returned, my question are:

1. if I iterate over `getGeneratedKeys()` and `foosHashSet` will ids return in same order so that each returned id from database belongs to corresponding Foo instance?
2. What about when I use multi thread and above code run in multiple threads simultaneously?
3. Is there any other solution for this? I have two table foo1 and foo2 and I want first insert foo1 records then use their primary ids as foo2 foreign key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given support for `getGeneratedKeys` for batch execution is not defined in the JDBC specification, the behavior will depend on the driver used. I would expect any driver that supports generated keys for batch execution, to return the ids in order they where added to the batch.

However the fact you are using a `Set` is problematic. Iteration order for most sets are not defined, and could change between iterations (usually only after modification, but in theory you can't assume anything about the order). You need to use something with a guaranteed order, eg a `List` or maybe a `LinkedHashSet`.

Applying multi-threading here would probably be a bad idea: you should only use a JDBC connection from a single-thread at a time. Accounting for multi-threading would either require correct locking, or requiring you to split up the workload so it can use separate connections. Whether that would improve or worsen performance is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to iterate through multiple generated keys without problem. They will return in the correct order they were inserted.
2. I think there should not be any problem adding threads in this matter. The only thing I'm pretty sure is that you would not be able to control the order the ids are inserted on both tables without some code complication.
3. You could store all firstly inserted ids on a Collection and after all threads/iterations have finished, insert them on second table.

Answer (score 0):

1. The iteration is the same as long as the fooHashSet is not altered.

   One could think using a `LinkedHashSet` which yields the items in order of insertion. Especially when nothing is removed or overwritten that would be nice.
2. Concurrent access would be problematic.

   Use `LinkedHashSet` without removal, only adding new items. And additionally wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedMap`. For set alterations one
   would need a Semaphore or such, as synchronizing such a large code block is a no-go.
3. An - even better performing - solution might be to make a local copy:

   ```
   List<Me> list = fooHashSet.stream().map(Foo::Me)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

   However this still is a somewhat unsatisfying solution:
   a batch for multiple inserts and then per insert several other updates/inserts.

   Transition to JPA instead of JDBC would somewhat alleviate the situation.

   After some experience however I would pose the question whether a *database* at that point is still the correct tool (hammer)? If it is a graph, a hierarchical data structure, then storing the entire data structure as XML with JAXB in a single database table, could be the best solution. Faster. Easier development. Verifiable data.
   Using the database for main data, and the XML for an edited/processed document.

Comment: How do you deduct that mohsenJsh is inserting a "graph" that is better represented by XML? All she/he is doing, is to do a bulk insert of multiple rows.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just had such a case this week. If mass data are manipulated, there are two cases: either indeed mass processing, or a data model of a hierarchy that is mapped to a database. If the generated keys are used _inside_ the "data model" then we are in the XML ready case. Otherwise not.

Comment: I think the more worrisome issue is the performance hit that comes from using more and more layers on top of your data, not the extra couple lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per the definition of executing batch it says

createFcCouponStatement.executeBatch()

Submits a batch of commands to the database for execution and if all commands execute successfully, returns an array of update counts. The int elements of the array that is returned are ordered to correspond to the commands in the batch, which are ordered according to the order in which they were added to the batch. The elements in the array returned by the method executeBatch may be one of the following:
A number greater than or equal to zero -- indicates that the command was processed successfully and is an update count giving the number of rows in the database that was affected by the command's execution

A value of SUCCESS_NO_INFO -- indicates that the command was processed successfully but that the number of rows affected is unknown
If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method throws a BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands in the batch. However, the driver's behavior must be consistent with a particular DBMS, either always continuing to process commands or never continuing to process commands. If the driver continues processing after a failure, the array returned by the method BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts will contain as many elements as there are commands in the batch, and at least one of the elements will be the following:

A value of EXECUTE_FAILED -- indicates that the command failed to execute successfully and occurs only if a driver continues to process commands after a command fails

The possible implementations and return values have been modified in the Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, version 1.3 to accommodate the option of continuing to process commands in a batch update after a BatchUpdateException object has been thrown.